Understanding OpenCV tonemapping implementation
Background
I'm following the OpenCV HDR tutorial here. I was getting NaN values when performing step 3 (tonemapping) so I had a look at the source for Tonemap.process() to see if I could figure out why this was happening. I'm now confused as to how this works at all.
The source is:
void process(InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst) CV_OVERRIDE
    {
        CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION();

        Mat src = _src.getMat();
        CV_Assert(!src.empty());
        CV_Assert(_src.dims() == 2 && _src.type() == CV_32FC3);
        _dst.create(src.size(), CV_32FC3);
        Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

        double min, max;
        minMaxLoc(src, &min, &max);
        if(max - min > DBL_EPSILON) {
            dst = (src - min) / (max - min);
        } else {
            src.copyTo(dst);
        }

        pow(dst, 1.0f / gamma, dst);
    }

(See here, Line 63.) I tried to write my own implementation of this in Python and realised that minMaxLoc() doesn't work for multi-channel arrays.
Question(s)
How does the above implementation work? It doesn't look like it should.
The process() method asserts that the source image is a 3-channel 32-bit floating point matrix, then calls minMaxLoc with that image. The docs for minMaxLoc state that it doesn't work for multi-channel images. If I pass a multi-channel matrix (from Python), then I get:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/minmax.cpp:1505: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) || (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) in function 'minMaxIdx'

The code which checks this assertion is:
void cv::minMaxIdx(InputArray _src, double* minVal,
                   double* maxVal, int* minIdx, int* maxIdx,
                   InputArray _mask)
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION();

    int type = _src.type(), depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(type), cn = CV_MAT_CN(type);
    CV_Assert( (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) ||
        (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) );

. . .

I can only assume that mask, minIdx, and maxIdx aren't affecting the outcome (as they aren't passed in, so my best guess is that the _mask.empty() and ![min|max]Idx checks come back true) so the above expression reduces to
CV_Assert(cn == 1 || cn > 1)

I wasn't sure what CV_MAT_CN(type) was returning here, my guess was the number of channels in the image. The macro (and related macros) are documented here. If I re-implement the macro:
/* macro_check.c */
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 512
#define SHIFT 3
#define MASK ((MAX - 1) << SHIFT)
#define CN(flags) ((((flags) & MASK) >> SHIFT) + 1)

int main(){
  int res = CN(21); // CV_32FC3 == 21
  printf("CN == %d\n", res);
  return 0;
}

This prints out:
CN == 3

The value for flags was chosen based on this table. Choosing random values from the table gives CN corresponding to the 'C' term of the type (i.e. it is the number of channels in the image).
While the documentation specifies that minMaxLoc doesn't work for multi-channel images, I'm actually now not sure why this assertion fails.
What am I missing here?

I seems the documentation of minMaxLoc lies a bit -- it does support multi-channel images, but only if you don't want a location, just the value. That's what that last part of the assert tells us. Now, the problem is with Python bindings for that function -- since it returns 4-tuple of minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc, there is no way in Python to call it to only get the value, not location (the wrapper sets a non-null pointer for all 4 output arguments). Use a numpy-based equivalent to get minimum and maximum in Python.

Probably worth posting a bug report on GitHub, to get the docs more accurate. I doubt the Python bindings are worth fixing -- it would have to be a hand-written function with a different name, and if we have Numpy around all the time, it's just reinventing a wheel.

when you've filed a bug report about this, you can then also submit a PR. changing the docs seems the simplest fix for this.

Might do that if the OP doesn't want to. I'll try to cobble up some answer to this when I'm back awake and have some time to do so, and do the PR+issue as well.

Looking at it now. Just want to make sure I get the details right. Will link here when done.

Issue posted, pull request linked from there (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/25784).
